# ThreeJS iOS shader warning "overflow in implicit constant conversion"

Tags: three.js

I'm just trying to remove as many warnings from our projects as possible, one of which I find quite horrible when instantiating a WebGL renderer on an iOS device a massive warning is thrown, it begins like so.....

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment WARNING: 0:53: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
```

and continues for 984 lines, then begins repeating itself!

I have attempted changing the precision value and with no luck of removing the warning, it seems to be just as soon as I instantiate a WebGL renderer, this is r73 again but I think its also still in r74.

If you run this example on iOS with a debugger connected you should see the massive warning just after the WebGLRenderer 73 log.

http://polygonprophecy.com/html5/wrapAroundTest/

Comment: Buddy did you found any solution?